# How to safely use django-ckeditor with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, ckeditor, code-injection

I've successfully implemented [`django-ckeditor`](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) with Django REST Framework and React, but I'm pretty sure that the way I've done it is not secure.

I've created an art blog, where each art piece has a rich-text description. Here's a basic example of one of my models with a rich-text field:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Artist(models.Model):
    biography = RichTextField(blank=True, null=False)
    ...
```

So, if saved his biography as "He was a ***nice guy!***", then DRF serializes that as:

```
<p>He was a <em><strong>nice guy!</strong></em></p>
```

In my React app, I render it with:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: artist.biography}} />
```

But, as the name implies, the [React documentation says that this is generally risky](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

This is a personal blog, so I'm not worried about other users injecting code into posts. However, I'm sure that someday I'll want to provide a rich-text editor for my users.

Is there a way to implement CKEditor with Django rest framework that doesn't require me to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? If not, how can I safely implement a rich-text editor, and still use it with DRF?

#### UPDATE

I've been doing a bit more research, and I've discovered something from Mozilla called Bleach. They describe it this way:

> Bleach is an allowed-list-based HTML sanitizing library that escapes or strips markup and attributes.

They go on to say:

> Bleach is intended for sanitizing text from *untrusted* sources. If you find yourself jumping through hoops to allow your site administrators to do lots of things, you're probably outside the use cases. Either trust those users, or don't.

So, in this case, I don't think I need it. Perhaps I'll use it in future projects though.

That still doesn't help me avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but this is the most practical solution that I can think of.

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't pertain to your question but I have to ask since you've managed to integrate DRF with CKeditor. I was wondering if you are able to actually POST any rich-text using DRF and if so, how.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician I haven't so far, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't. I've only used it in the Admin site. I'm pretty sure that `RichTextField` is just a subclass of `models.TextField` with a different widget. The text that you `POST` is supposed to have HTML tags in it, but it doesn't have to and it isn't special. You should be able to use plain old JavaScript CKEditor in a form that you post like any other data. Think of it as a fancy `<textarea>` field. This might be helpful: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_framed.html